# 10,000 records for code id, code title, code desc and vendor - Import

Tags: custom-list, search-results

I received a bunch of mechanical data with CodeID, CodeTitle, CodeDesc from different vendors, SourceVendor. I have not counted the records but it's 10 to 15k. The idea is to import this data into SharePoint list.

Also provide a UI so manager can look at the code and get the respected title and description. Now the challenging part is most of these data are duplicated except codeID. Different vendor has their own analysis on each code. Most of the time the title matches but description varies. For example,

Vendor ABC data looks like this
"DH-100", "Downhole pipe", "bunch of details about this downhole pipe"

now vendor xyz have a similar title or exact same title with their own analysis

"234.23.443", "Downhole pvc pipe" "bunch of details about this"

Should I create a advanced search page where user will select "Code Title" and let sharepoint search bring me the result in list view format? Or are there other fancy way to tackle this.

Also, Should I maintain different list based on vendor or dump all the data into one large list?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. SharePoint 2010. I just wanted better recommendation. Are there any good white paper on these type of requirements?

Comment: NP, it all depends on your requirements, there is no best practice as the business requirements should drive how you build the solution. Personally I don't like list view, but that's me.

Comment: Hi Matthew, business requirements is pretty much what I have laid out in the main post. I just want to better design back-end. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create a content type that handled the fields and then build a list based on the Content Type. From there you could write a couple filter web parts or use the SharePoint Search Services to handle the list queries for the user. Search is much faster than other access methods. (Actually all this is easier in 2013, but you probably guessed I'd say that.)

As for one list or many, prototype both, but you'll probably find one list is easier, unless security becomes an issue.